# delete row from mysql based on information in other tables gives unintelligible error message

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete rows from a first table based on information found in another related table.  The first test is that I get the correct rows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from stationinfluence where stationinfluence.station_id = 12024 and exists (select 1 from star where star.id = `stationinfluence`.`star_id` and pow(pow(star.x - -6,2)+pow(star.y-5,2),0.5) > 300);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just using `select *` shows it's the correct row.  So that's fine.  But if I take the exact same statement, but change the `select count(*)` to `delete`, I get an error message I can't understand:

```
mysql> delete from stationinfluence where stationinfluence.station_id = 12024 and exists (select 1 from star where star.id = stationinfluence.star_id and pow(pow(star.x - -6,2)+pow(star.y-5,2),0.5) > 300);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 's.star_id' in 'where clause'
```

I have no idea where it's getting this `s.star_id` from.

This database has no views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that s.star_id was referenced in an `after delete` trigger, changing that trigger resolved this problem.